# Why do I keep getting error in list box multiple selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a multi-selection box - using a script I found online, my VBA is pretty much nil. I keep getting next without for error

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    myVAR = ""

    For x = 0 To Me.Requirements.ListCount - 1
        If Me.Requirements.Selected(x) Then
            If myVAR = "" Then
                myVAR = Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
            Else
                myVAR = myVAR & "," & Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
        End If
    Next x

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("v2") = myVAR
    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing an ```end if``` add that in and the error will go away.

Comment: Warcupine is right. If you indent your code (one TAB per If/Next/With...) then it is easy to see

Answer (score 2):

The original code from [rev 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58014148/1) better highlights the problem than the current code in the OP:

> ```
> Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
>
> myVAR = ""
>
> For x = 0 To Me.Requirements.ListCount - 1
> If Me.Requirements.Selected(x) Then
> If myVAR = "" Then
> myVAR = Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
> Else
> myVAR = myVAR & "," & Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
> End If
> Next x
>
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("v2") = myVAR
> Me.Hide
>
> End Sub
> ```

If you're unsure how to correctly and consistenly indent your code, you can use an [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) tool, and then you can simply follow the indentation levels:

```
For x = 0 To Me.Requirements.ListCount - 1
|   If Me.Requirements.Selected(x) Then
|   |   If myVAR = "" Then
|   |   |   myVAR = Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
|   |   Else
|   |   |   myVAR = myVAR & "," & Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
|   |   End If
|   Next x '<~ not lined up!
*woopsie*
```

Referring to the code as it appears in the current revision, the inner `If...Else` block isn't terminated, so the compiler is taking the *outer* `End If` in its place, and then runs into `Next` when it expects `End If` - hence the "next without for" compile error.

The correct code would be:

```
For x = 0 To Me.Requirements.ListCount - 1
|   If Me.Requirements.Selected(x) Then
|   |   If myVAR = "" Then
|   |   |   myVAR = Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
|   |   Else
|   |   |   myVAR = myVAR & "," & Me.Requirements.List(x, 0)
|   |   End If
|   End If
Next x
```